# How to set up the middleware to run a react & angular apps side by side in a asp.net core MVC app?

Tags: angular, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have an **angular & react app (clientapp1 & clientapp2)** in the same **asp.net core 2.1 app**. I can run the apps in it's folders **clientapp1** and **clientapp2**. They run in it's own ports and work fine.

I added the following code to branch the paths. I want the angular app to run when I use the endpoint `http://localhost:5000/clientapp1` and run the react app when I run `http://localhost:5000/clientapp2`.

```
app.Map("/clientapp1", clientapp1 =>
{
    clientapp1.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp1";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
});

app.Map("/clientapp2", clientapp2 =>
{
    clientapp2.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp2";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
});
```

The asp.net core application does not work when run the command `dotnet run` in the application root folder. I get the following errors. The error says it looks for the files in the http://localhost:5000/ folder.

**Angular:**

[image]

**React:**

[image]

What configuration I have to set up to tell both the apps where to look for the files.

I can make it work if I change the code `clientapp1.UseSpa(spa =>` to `app.UseSpa(spa =>`. But the side effect is that the `http://localhost:5000/clientapp2` does not work.

Comment: I wonder if adding `/clientapp1` to the `base href` in the *index.html* of the Angular app would fix this. I don't know enough about react to know if that would need something similar.

Comment: I tried that, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you must have two scripts and add --serve-path and --base-href in your scripts. Typically you have in your package.json

```
{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start:app1": "ng serve --base-href=/clientapp1/ --serve-path=/clientapp1", 
    "start:app2": "ng serve --base-href=/clientapp2/ --serve-path=/clientapp2", 
    "build": "ng build",
     ...
  },
  ....
}
```

And in your startup.cs, e.g.

```
//for app1
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
   spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start:app1");
}
//for app2
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
   spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start:app2");
}
```

Comment: Recenty I wrote in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815456/asp-net-core-2-1-angular-6-0-spa-template-razor-page-cshtml-for-index-instea/51581739#51581739 as use razor page and in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746009/net-core-2-1-base-href-tag-on-angular-template/51571218#51571218 as change package to add absolute path to the scripts

Comment: The ```clientapp1``` & ```clientapp2``` in my app are angular and react. So the start scripts will not work. The react app has it's own ```package.json``` in it's clientapp2 folder.

Comment: I tried your suggestion for the angular app, but I get error ```Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost:5001/clientapp1/polyfills.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.```. That error repeats for all the ```*.bundle.js``` files.

Comment: I looked at your stackoverflow question. Your application is an angular application as well as has only one middleware branch. In my app, there are two - one for angular and one for react.

Comment: You always can try run ng-serve independently, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#run-ng-serve-independentlyuse , but i'am not sure that this is you want. I don't know much about react, but I think that the problem becomes from you forget --serve-path. (I think I can not help you more, sorry). nut I llok like is strange you use the same script to server two different applications

Comment: Running the angular & react apps separately in their folders work. The problem may be that the ```ng serve``` is not generating the bundle JS files or dropping them in a folder structure other than ```wwwroot``` so they can't be located. The same issue may be for the react app too.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to configure your CORS configuration. After you configure that
[CORS setting in Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRSIX.png)

And after that you will notice your middleware being called only after some particular request is made so in initial load of your page middleware will not be called. I don't really know how it's really done but for me I just called random URL from my front end and middleware gets called.