# Deploy Single Angular 5 project to multiple clients with different URLs

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I am using Angular 5.2 version for my new project. I have deployed it over to the DEV location with the URL

```
http://XX.XX.XX.XX/myDev/app/login
```

when I run the `ng build` command

```
ng build -aot -ec --prod --base-href=/myDev/
```

Now I want to run the application for multiple clients and the URL will change to something like this

```
http://XX.XX.XX.XX/myDev/**Client-X**/app/login
http://XX.XX.XX.XX/myDev/**Client-Y**/app/login
```

Client-X & Client-Y are virtual directories in IIS.

Please suggest, how do I run this application and make the changes to the `base-href` while performing the `ng build`

In my case, i would have one deployment but different URL's pointing to the same package.

Comment: The `base-href` change is very conditional, what you're asking is more of a server issue than an Angular issue.

Comment: You will have problems with --base-ref and --serve-path. You must use APP_BASE_HREF to change the base ref and put the href of the script in absolute url. Maybe this mine answer to a problem about .NET can throw a few ligths of the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746009/net-core-2-1-base-href-tag-on-angular-template/51571218#51571218 talk about the problem and a possible solution (well, I think in .NET Core, but the reason is the same)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `environment.ts` file by creating separate environment files for each clients. Each environment should contain `baseURL` const variable, which will be available in the runtime code.

```
ng build --prod --env=environment-clientA
```

Hope, this helps

Comment: That's not a scalable soln, because we might many hundred clients. The app will be same for different client with few changes relative to stylesheets and CSS.

Comment: @Karan Of course it's scalable, that's the sole purpose of environment files.

Comment: But i want to keep the enironment files only for the env related config changes such as API endpoints, folder names etc..

Comment: This works for the question stated  Why would an application maintain unique CSS files per client?  An application should have a single template which the design is based on, and possibly tweaked from client suggestions. Even If you do need to have custom CSS for client specific app. this still is fine, it all boils down to how you designed your components / project.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it using token replacement.

So when I do build production all my URLS or environment.prod.ts will have tokens #{CLIENT_URL} and so on, means that compiled/bundled files will have INVALID urls or configuration settings, also it means that without modifications (replacing) my bundle will not work.

After build I will receive Artifacts and then each deployment will be replacing and putting its own properties.

In VSTS (if you are azure user ) there is extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens  which will replace, But you can write your own script

Benefit is that after you build solution you always deploy same version to any environment you want.

So when you deploy for customer 1 you replace in all files #{CLIENT_URL} with https://client1.com for other customer with other url.

Comment: When you deploy for client 1. you replace in all js files #{CLIENT_URL}  to https://client1.com, for second to https://client2.com

Comment: @Karan I hope i got you problem properly. this is solution if you have multiple deployments. Because if you have one deployment but different URLs then solution would be different

Comment: My need is different. I have one deployment but different URLs for the different clients. Please suggest the solution in that.

Comment: @Karan dont have solution yet, but will try to make git example

Comment: Thanks :-)  for the help