# .net Core 2.2 Angular template - Base href

Tags: c#, angular, iis, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using the .Net Core 2.2 Angular template and i'm hosting it with IIS.

The main problem is that my Index.html has the standard base href. I want it to be variable and its not known when i build it. So `app.Map()` is not the right way and neither any angular.json build parameters.

The problem came with the new [Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746009/net-core-2-1-base-href-tag-on-angular-template) and i did not find a good solution for this.

Right now im using [Sharmachines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084260/11208896) Solution but it's more like a Workaround for me since it doesnt work well when it doesnt lay in a subdirectory.

Any clues how to achive this without an Installer?

Thank you for helping