# Change base href with ng serve (Angular 15)

Tags: angular

I have an application in Angular 15 and I want to be able to start it in two or more different paths at the same time, for example in "http://localhost:4200/site1" and "http://localhost:4200/site2" (having subdomains or changing port is not an option for the client and I want to test this without having to deploy to a development server each time we change code).

I have found the option --serve-path so if I do "ng serve --serve-path site1" and "ng serve --serve-path site2" the path works but I don't get the contents because of the base tag in index.html ("`<base href='/' />`") and I can't change it because I need to have the two sites open at same time.

I have found that some people say that in previous versions ng serve had two options for that ("--base-href", and "--deploy-url"), but in Angular 15 they don't exist.

How can I get this in Angular 15?

Thanks.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this old [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746009/net-core-2-1-base-href-tag-on-angular-template/51571218#51571218) -really I don't know if work-

try use

```
  <script>
    var items = document.location.href.split('/');
    while (items.length>4)
      items.pop();
    document.write('<base href="' + items.join('/') + '" />');
  </script>
```

Comment: This solved my issue about the base tag but now I got another one: ng serve doesn't let me start the same application twice in the same port (even using different serve-path). Is there a way to fix that without the need to publish in a development server each time we make changes in our code?

Answer (score 0):

You could create two different configurations and change the index.html in them

in angular.json

```json
{
...
"configurations":{
   "site1":{
      "fileReplacements":[
         {
            "replace":"src/index.html",
            "with":"src/environments/environment.site1.index.html"
         }
      ]
   }
}
...
}
```

then

```
ng serve --serve-path site1 configuration=site1
```